# Apple 4s Using Tracfone BYOP

Tags: iphone, sim, meid

I am looking into buying a used Apple 4s to use as a Tracfone through Tracfone BYOP. I want to be sure that I know my facts before investing money into this venture. Please let me know if I'm missing something or have the wrong info.

Tracfone BYOP Requirements:

Used Apple iPhone 4 or 4s/
Verizon Carrier/
Clean ESN/
UNLOCKED/
Must Have Verizon SIM Card/
Must be CDMA

Question ~~ Does the iPhone HAVE To Have A SIM Card?

ANY Help Will Certainly Be Appreciated! Thank-You!

Comment: Are you simply asking whether the iPhone requires a SIM card for activation? Could you expand on what the rest of your question is regarding?

Comment: Verizon is a CDMA carrier. AT&T and T-mobile are GSM carriers.  A Verizon iPhone 4 doesn't have a SIM card slot, a Verizon iPhone 4S does have a SIM card slot.  Therefore the single line of requirements data you have provided is inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

I have just activated (Nov 20, 2014) an iPhone 4s that had been on the Verizon System.  It had to be unlocked for international use.  It had to be active on the Verizon System to do the unlocking.  The previous owner of the phone kept the sim card so it does NOT have a sim card installed.  It functions 100% as a Tracfone.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, Verizon phones don't use SIM cards. The iPhone 4s (and I think the 4) does have a SIM slot because it can be used on either CDMA or GSM, but you don't use that for Tracfone's BYOP. The phone does need to have been previously on Verizon, and be unlocked.

I've done this twice with a used 4s each time, buying one from eBay & one from Amazon. It costs $10 to register each phone with Tracfone. On eBay I get 200 minute cards for $32 that triple to 600 voice minutes, 600 texts, and 600 MB of data for 90 days. It's great for moderate use, especially if you're on wi-fi a lot and you use Apple's iMessage feature for some of your texting. I also use YouMail for voice mail, which avoids Tracfone's clumsy voice mail that charges you for both your calls to listen AND your callers' time leaving messages.

There's a lot of useful information in the comments here, including links to even cheaper airtime:

http://www.prepaidphoneguy.com/tracfone-iphone-arrives

I think it's wise to the extra $$ to get the iPhone 4s over the 4, for its extra speed and capabilities. Ours run iOS 7 pretty well (although I haven't spoiled myself by trying a 5s).

Comment: The domain seems to have been abandoned.