# iphone 4s for Tracfone BYOP?

Tags: iphone

I would like to use an iphone 4s for the Tracfone BYOP program. Does the iphone 4s have to be used to work on the Tracfone BYOP program, or can I use a new phone?

Comment: already answered in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141289/apple-4s-using-tracfone-byop

Needs to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I have just activated (Nov 20, 2014) an iPhone 4s that had been on the Verizon System. It had to be unlocked for international use. It had to be active on the Verizon System to do the unlocking. The previous owner of the phone kept the sim card so it does NOT have a sim card installed. It is 100% functional on the Tracfone system.  I am not on any plan preferring to add minutes/text/data as I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new phone or a used 4s. The only requirement to use TracFone's Straight Talk BYOP program is that it has to be unlocked, off contract and a clean IMEI. The only plan you can use with iPhone through tracfone is their straight talk ulimited $45 per month (also sold for a discount annual card). Those are available at walmart or at www.straighttalk.com

I have a iPhone 5s on TracFone's Straight Talk and I absolutely LOVE it!